# Scroll Right JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Добрый вечер!
Есть контейнер 1024x768 в нем блоки 220x220, скролл горизонтальный!

Как реализовать, чтобы скролл при появлении был всегда вправо???

```css
.main {
 width:1024px;
 height:768px;
 border:1px solid red;
 overflow-x: none;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: wrap;
 flex-direction:column; 
}
.item {
 width:220px;
 height:220px;
 background: green;
 border:1px solid blue;
 float:left; 
 margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас неточности в стилях, вы используете float внутри flex-контейнера что априори некорректно. Иногда для таких задач я использую `inline-block` у child-элементов и свойство `white-space: nowrap;` у родителя.

Comment: спасибо за замечание, но float просто забыл убрать =)

Answer (score 1):

В `jQuery` есть метод `scrollLeft`. Это позиция горизонтального скролла. Надо просто ему передать значение ширины самого элемента.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.main').scrollLeft($('.main').width());
});
```

```css
.main {
 width:1024px;
 height:768px;
 border:1px solid red;
 overflow-x: none;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: wrap;
 flex-direction:column; 
}
.item {
 width:220px;
 height:220px;
 background: green;
 border:1px solid blue;
 float:left; 
 margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Вот и второй вариант на чистом `javascript`.

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
element.scrollLeft = element.offsetWidth;
```

```css
.main {
  width:1024px;
  height:768px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex-direction:column; 
}
.item {
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
  background: green;
  border:1px solid blue;
  float:left; 
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не обязательно делать `$('.main').width();` для рядовых задач думаю достаточно `$('.main').scrollLeft(9999);`

Comment: @ferrari А в чем проблема? ПК зависать будет от одного метода больше?

Comment: Особо нет, но работать будет в 4 раза медленнее примерно. Коммент был к тому чтобы автор и пользователи знали что можно задать бесконечно большой scrollLeft ( или scrollTop ) что-бы оказаться справа ( или внизу) блока. А ещё иногда `$.width()` может не хватить, когда за него вываливаются марджины, если уж вычесляете ширину, то пользуйтесь `$.outerWidth()`

Comment: @ferrari Не знаю как вы производите расчеты, но по вашим расчетам большее часть сегодняшних сайтов должны зависать от одного клика или же от одной анимации.

Comment: Обновил коммент)

Comment: @ferrari И с паддингами работать будет если задать в стилях `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: без jQuery никак??? нужно на чистом js

Comment: @ntym Посмотрите обновленный ответ.